# Zend Route not working in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes

i'm currently debugging a Zend application and parts of the routing are not working in Chrome - all other Browsers do what they are supposed to. In Chrome, i get forwarded to the Errorpage and i get following message:

```
Cannot load controller class "TestUrlController" from file "master/src/application/modules/default/controllers/TestUrlController.php
```

for url /de/shop/test-url, which means it is using the default router, while it actually should use the "shopController" as registered in the Bootstrap.php:

```
$routeShops = new \Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '@properties/:shopurl',
            array(
                'module' => 'location',
                'controller' => 'shop',
                'action' => 'details',
                'shopurl' => null
            )
        );
```

As said, all other Browsers work just fine. Where do I even start here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests sent from Chrome do not correctly resolve to the right controller, as the '@properties' part for some reason is not recognized. When hardcoded, it works.